# Android SherlockFragmentActivity - Tab

Tags: android

I use SherlockFragmentActivity and I have:

```
public class TestActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


    private static enum Tab {
        Test1("test1", TestOneFragment.class),
        Test2("test2", TestTwoFragment.class),
        private final String title;
        private final Class<? extends Fragment> clazz;

        private Tab(String title, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz) {
            this.title = title;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        private String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        private Class<? extends Fragment> getFragmentClass() {
            return clazz;
        }
    }
```

It works fine ,because I have Test1 and Test2 in the same "package".

How add external "package" class ? When I import com.bla.blaa.BlaActivity;
I use this like this:

```
 private static enum Tab {
        Blabla("Blabla", BlaActivity.class),
        Test1("test1", TestOneFragment.class),
        Test2("test2", TestTwoFragment.class);
```

I have error:

```
The constructor TestActivity.Tab(String, Class<BlaActivity>) is 
     undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass to the SherlockFragmentActivity constructor class that doesn't extend a fragment. It seems that your are trying to pass an activity (BlaActivity.class) to Tab. SherlockFragmentActivity works with fragments. You might start other application from one of the tabs using intents:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: I want to add another (external) application to the tab.

Comment: I don't think you can encapsulate another application that way if it wasn't designed to let you do that. It would be as security flaw, because it would allow someone to pretend that you're in another app and reach into its code in ways that it shouldn't.